# Hate reCAPTCHA - CakePHP Captcha Alternative?

Tags: php, cakephp, captcha, recaptcha

I want to add captcha to my website and I currently have reCAPTCHA installed but I hate it.  They make some of the images so hard to enter I know this is going to annoy my customers and they will just end up leaving.

I'm just looking for a simple captcha that will work with CakePHP; can anyone recommend any alternatives to reCAPTCHA that will work with CakePHP?

Thank you!

Comment: CakePHP is PHP, therefore, if it works with PHP, it will work with CakePHP.

Answer (score 4):

CakePHP is just a framework that runs on PHP.  Any CAPTCHA that works with PHP will work with CakePHP.  [Google](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=php%20captcha) [shows](http://www.phpcaptcha.org/) [many](http://code.google.com/p/cool-php-captcha/) [are](http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2011/01/a-simple-php-captcha-script/) [out](http://www.webappers.com/2009/09/29/open-source-php-captcha-for-your-forms/) [there](http://www.ejeliot.com/pages/php-captcha).

Think about how you integrated reCAPTCHA into your site...  reCAPTCHA doesn't have a CakePHP-specific plugin (at least not that I'm aware of) so you would integrate any other PHP CAPTCHA the same way.

Comment: +1 for the multiple google links in the single sentence. Your sarcasm was not lost on me.

Answer (score 0):

Akismet is my favorite when it comes to spam protection. and it is much effective. more about akismet can be found here http://akismet.com/

Answer (score 0):

Did you check [securimage](http://www.phpcaptcha.org/)? It works on your own server and you can adjust many specs.

Answer (score 0):

I use a simple math captcha as well as a passive captcha:
http://www.dereuromark.de/2010/08/09/how-to-implement-captchas-properly/

the math captcha also works for handicapped people but is very basic.
the passive captcha is hidden and invisible to frontend users but assert basic protection from bots etc.

you can easily write some captcha functionality yourself. just remember not to use sessions in a way that you break multiple tabs (really bad coding but seen quite often).